# File.Exists returns false in UnitTest context

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have dumped a file with some data for UnitTesting.
When the code tries to load the file, it gets FileNotFoundException.

Data and code files next to each other in the same folder.

- Project.Test

  - data.xml
  - data.cs

Comment: I'd just like to point out that if you are reading from disk you are not writing a unit test. Unit tests run in memory, all external resources should be abstracted using test doubles (home-made or via frameworks)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Test projects needs to copy the files after the build in the bin/Debug folder. It is only done if you set the "**Copy to Output Directory**" property to "**Copy always**".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be appropriate for your purpose or not, but I'll often include sample/data/other files as embedded resources. If you choose to do this, you'll still need to set the `Build Action` property on the file in Solution Explorer, but then you don't need to worry about where a file is or if it exists.

Here's a sample method for reading the file. I'd suggest changing the method to return data as a string, XDocument, or other more-suitable format if it fits your data type. `resource` will be the project path to the file (i.e., `Project.Test.data.xml` in your example above).

```
private byte[] GetEmbeddedResourceBytes(string resource)
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resource)) {
        if (stream != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                int read;
                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```